# dispose every instance in Java

Tags: java, dispose

I have a class which calls people's profiles. I can have as many profiles as needed opened at the same time, but when I am calling the method `dispose()` from the parent class, it disposes ONLY the last profile opened. How can I dispose all of them?

This is the action of the button that disposes. the button calls the dispose method of class A which is "dispose class B" and then disposes itself.

```
    private void logout_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) throws SQLException {
        String [] args = null ;
        JavaClient client = new JavaClient();

        try {
            client.main(args);
        } catch (Exception f) {
        }
        terms.disposeOthers();
        terms.dispose();
        dispose();
}
```

terms.dispose() and dispose() are the built in methods of java but
I also created the terms.disposeOthers() like this:

```
public void disposeOthers(){
    profile.dispose();

}
```

It is inside Class B

Comment: shw the implementation of dispose ?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your other instances are attached to other "parent" objects, therefore they cannot be disposed (only the last one is possible because you didn't attach it?).

why don't you dispose the entire container?